# MTOUCH: error MT0010: Could not parse the command line arguments:

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have followed all the steps from https://university.xamarin.com/lightninglectures/ios-bindings-in-cc to map C library in Xamarin iOS app.
But when I am trying to build the xamarin IOS app it giving below error.

```
Tool /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch execution started with arguments: --cache /Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache --sim /Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/simpleBindings.app --executable simpleBindings --debug --nolink --sdkroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer --sdk 10.2 --targetver 10.2 --http-message-handler=HttpClientHandler --tls-provider=default --abi=x86_64 --symbollist /Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-symbols.list --dsym=no -cxx -lexample -force_load /Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings/libexample.a” --gcc_flags “-L/Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings -r /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.dll -r /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Xml.dll -r /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Core.dll -r /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll -r /Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/ExampleLib/bin/Debug/ExampleLib.dll -r /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/mscorlib.dll -r /Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/ExampleLib/bin/Debug/ExampleLib.dll --target-framework Xamarin.iOS,v1.0 /Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug//simpleBindings.exe -v -v 
MTOUCH: error MT0010: Could not parse the command line arguments: Mono.Options.OptionException: Cannot use unregistered option 'o' in bundle '-force_load'.
  at Mono.Options.OptionSet.ParseBundledValue (System.String f, System.String n, Mono.Options.OptionContext c) [0x00086] in <e61e7c7e12a34f76bb60aae297cbc79c>:0 
  at Mono.Options.OptionSet.Parse (System.String argument, Mono.Options.OptionContext c) [0x000ce] in <e61e7c7e12a34f76bb60aae297cbc79c>:0 
  at Mono.Options.OptionSet.Parse (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] arguments) [0x000b8] in <e61e7c7e12a34f76bb60aae297cbc79c>:0 
  at Xamarin.Bundler.Driver.Main2 (System.String[] args) [0x01667] in <e61e7c7e12a34f76bb60aae297cbc79c>:0 
Task "MTouch" execution -- FAILED
Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "/Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings/simpleBindings.csproj".-- FAILED
Done building project "/Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings/simpleBindings.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/Users/san/Projects/ExampleLib/simpleBindings/simpleBindings.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets (_CompileToNative target) ->

MTOUCH: error MT0010: Could not parse the command line arguments: Mono.Options.OptionException: Cannot use unregistered option 'o' in bundle '-force_load'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the options, like `-force_load`, are not options for `mtouch` but for the native linker.

They should be given to `mtouch`, between quotes, under the `-gcc_flags` argument.

You likely did not add them correctly (wrong order or no quotes) to the **Additional mtouch arguments** in your project options.

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming because of copy paste of command in mtouch arguments 
i.e. -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lexample -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libexample.a

After manually changing double quote in mtouch argument problem is resolved.